# How to exclude a link in a smooth scrolling script? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap 3 carousel on my website.
I am also using this jQuery script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

                if (target.length) 
                {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                      scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that, when sliding the carousel, it clicks the `#carousel` link. This makes the carousel unfunctional.

What I am wondering is, is it possible to exclude `#carousel` from the script? So the script does not apply for `#carousel`, but does apply to all other links.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it to the selector

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href=#carousel])')
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I tried this but it did not work. :-(
EDIT: It works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, yeah.. typo. Removed before I saw your comment. More about the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS selector to the ignore: in the constructor, add the selector to your scrollable anchors

```js
var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {

 // Selectors
 ignore: '[data-scroll-ignore]'
  
});
```

```html
<a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#nav-tab-card" data-scroll-ignore>
```